# Why do many news sites have pictures misplaced until I select the text that is there under these false pics.?

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome

Win 7, Dell 6420, Chrome.

This has happened for the last couple of months.

I will go to a newspaper site, example Guardian in the UK. As I scroll down, pictures and parts of pictures will appear in the wrong place, covering text.

I can remove them by left-clicking near the wrong place where they appear and selecting, as if selecting the text to copy. As I "select" over the picture, or part of the picture there, it will disappear. This may happen numerous times on a site. It is intermittent.

Comment: A list of your browser addons might help here.  How long has this been happening for?  Screenshots and a link to a publicly available website might help too.  This sounds like the kind of thing a badly written ad-blocker or extension might do...

Comment: Enabled extensions: Google docs, Google docs offline, Google sheets, Google slides. It's been happening for a couple of months. I'll try to get a screen shot. http://www.cbc.ca/news, http://www.theguardian.com/uk are a couple, it only happens on news sites.

Comment: The news sucks lately, so you're not missing much.  I wish I could get the news covered by misplaced pictures on my own computer.  :-)

Comment: For some reason??? this has not happened since I posted this.